# Canvas Background Color

Tags: smartface.io

how can i set the canvas background? its always shown black. if i set the fillcolor its just filling the circle, outside is still black.

```
this.drawArc({
    x1 : 10,
    y1 : 10,
    x2 : "95%",
    y2 : "95%",
    startAngle : -270,
    endAngle : 90,
    useCenterLines : false,
    paint : {
        type : 0,
        fillColor : null,
        strokeColor : "#cccccc",
        width: 20
    }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Background color of the Canvas object is not a changeable property.

Android uses it as Black , iOS uses is as Transparent.

These are native behaviours of Canvas objects.

Answer (score 0):

i think nearest solution is using drawimage before drawing canvas object

```
this.drawImage({
    image:"imagebg2.png", // image filled by bg color
    destRect : [0, 0, this.Canvas1.width, this.Canvas1.height]
});
```

but its rendering colors different